# RDoc XML generation

Tags: xml, ruby, rdoc

I'm trying to generate a RDoc using the XML format. Here's the command that I'm using:

```
$ rdoc --fmt=xml --opname=api.xml
```

The file is created but no method list is generated. I'm using `rdoc (2.4.3)`. The RDoc template for XML include tags for method displaying.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2.4, XML output has been unsupported. See e.g. [this blog](http://blog.segment7.net/articles/category/rdoc) by one of the maintainers:

> Moved HTML and XML generators to unmaintained
>
> - No gem will be provided as it’s too difficult to make them work
> - Removed options—one-file,—style=,—inline-source,—promiscuous, —op-name

I don't think you can be running 2.4.3 - the options you specify in your example don't work for this version. I've just downloaded the latest gem and confirmed this:

```
$ rdoc --format=xml --opname=api.xml 
invalid argument: --format=xml
```

Perhaps you have an older version of `rdoc` installed that appears earlier in your `$PATH`?

I tried `rdoc 1.0.1` and got the behaviour you describe (XML output, no methods). So it looks like the answer to your question is "no, it's not possible (was buggy, now not supported)".

You could try suggesting this as a [feature request](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/?group_id=627), although it sounds like it's not going to happen for a while, if ever.